# i want to show the default admin permission in another way

Tags: python, django, django-admin

[image: i want to remove the app name and model name show only the last one while selecting]

i want to remove the app name and model name show only the last one while selecting in the group making page. When showing those permission those app name and content type does not gets remove. Make the adjustment in front side only to show the code name only

Comment: the app name and model name are present because the permission will only apply to that model in that app. If you remove these, you may have permissions that seem like they are duplicates but are not. Is this your intention?

Comment: YES, that was my intention but i only want to view that in front only no changes in back end part

Comment: what do you mean by "no changes in back end part" do you mean you don't want to override the admin interface? Because there is no way to achieve this without some amount of overriding.